# Uploading a React-rendered SVG

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

In my App, users can make little drawings in SVG, which I render using React. I'd like to upload the SVG to my server.

How could I render the SVG to a Javascript Image, so I can upload it to my server? Google searches don't return meaningful results.

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to react, but to convert an in doc `<svg>` to an svg file, you just need to serialize its markup to string (cf [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer)) and append the resulting string in a Blob and upload the Blob to your server.

But if you want a complete stand-alone svg document, with doctype and namespaces, here is an example of how to do it :

```js
function svgNodeToBlob(node) {
  // first an doctype
  var svgDocType = document.implementation.createDocumentType('svg', "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN", "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd");
  // then a new SVG Document
  var svgDoc = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg', svgDocType);
  // set its documentElement to our root svg node (well a clone of it)
  svgDoc.replaceChild(node.cloneNode(true), svgDoc.documentElement);
  // serialize the document
  var svgData = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svgDoc);
  // convert to a blob
  var blob = new Blob([svgData], {
    type: 'image/svg+xml; charset=utf8'
  });
  return blob;
}

var blob = svgNodeToBlob(document.querySelector('svg'));
// from here you can send the blob to your server

// for the demo, we'll just make an downloadable link from it
var a = document.querySelector('a');
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.download = 'mycoolsvgfile.svg';
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect width="50" height="50" x="20" y="10"/>
</svg>
<a>download as file</a>
```

But note that all external resources that had influences on your node won't have on the file (i.e if you do some styling with CSS from an external Stylesheet). In this case, you'd have to append a clone of these external elements inside the cloned node before appending it to the SVG document.